# css:setting background colour on a span causes background to obscure text

Tags: html, css

The simplest way to explain my problem is by example:

```
<p style="line-height:1;">
<span style="background-color:yellow">ggggg<br>TTTT
</span>
```

or if you prefer, https://jsfiddle.net/k17760zr/

you can see that the highlighting on the 'T's overlaps the bottom of the 'g's obscuring the text. However, if you remove the highlighting, there's visually no interference between the two lines, and it's even possible to use the mouse to select the T without obscuring the g, so it doesn't seem that the lines overlap.

I realise I could work around this by changing the line height or by setting the background color of the whole paragraph, but those aren't suitable in my circumstances. Is there any way I can preserve the line height and still highlight individual spans in the paragraph without the highlight overlapping the line above?

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: inline-block` on the `<span>`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k17760zr/2/)

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p style="line-height:1;"> <span style="background-color:yellow">ggggg<br />TTTT
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that's really useful but I don't think it will work for me. In my application, the span I'm highlighting will be a sequence of words within the paragraph which will wrap round several lines. inline block disrupts the natural text wrapping

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the line-height of p.

```
<p style="line-height:1.2;"> 
    <span style="background-color:yellow">ggggg<br />TTTT</span>
</p>
```

Comment: As I said in the original question, "I realise I could work around this by changing the line height or by setting the background color of the whole paragraph, but those aren't suitable in my circumstances."